# Attended Call Transfer in Twilio

Tags: twilio

I am trying to create an attended transfer using Twilio.

The flow I would like is as follows:

```
1. Existing call with two legs (client side, agent side)

2. Using API put Client on HOLD and put Agent 1 in Conference

3. Using API Put Agent 2 into same Conference

4. Agent 1 and Agent 2 can speak without Client hearing

5. Using API add Client to Conference

6. Client, Agent 1 and Agent 2 can speak together

7. Using API Agent 1 can be disconnected from the call
```

Is it possible to do this?

Or do we need to create a conference for all our inbound and outbound calls?

(even though only about 5% of our calls get transferred)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can definitely do this. It might be easier to do this from the context of a conference in the first place, as you can take advantage of [putting conference participants on hold](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/participant#instance-post).

To do it from a regular call to start with, you would want to redirect one of the agent or caller to new TwiML and then make sure the other leg of the call had somewhere to continue to with the existing TwiML. It's probably easier to [transfer the agent's call with the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state#post) and then make sure that the TwiML you originally return to the user continues to place them into a queue using [`<Enqueue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/enqueue) that you can then call them out of later, or simply a looping [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks Phil.  I'll dig into the code now that I know it's possible.  Will be in touch if I get stuck.

Comment: Hope it goes well!

Comment: When we transfer either the parent or child of the existing call, it drops the other.  How can we give the other leg 'somewhere to continue to' like you suggest?  Thanks

Comment: You'd need more TwiML after the connecting `<Dial>` that Twilio would then execute once the call had disconnected. In this case, because you have an incoming call which makes the `<Dial>` onto the agent, I would include an `<Enqueue>` after the `<Dial>` that places the caller into a queue, waiting to be called back by the agent.